# CSS3 transforms: how to undo a transform operation?

Tags: javascript, animation, css, css-transforms

I want to apply a translate transformation to a `<div>`, and then be able to return that `<div>` to its original place.

Applying the same operation with negated values doesn't return the DIV to the original place in the screen:

- Applied translation: `-webkit-transform: translate(300px, 400px);`
- The "undo" effect that is not working: `-webkit-transform: translate(-300px, -400px);`

I want to control the undo levels, so reseting the transforms is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think you can apply multiple instances of the same transform function to an element. I think the second `-webkit-transform:translate();` statement *replaces* the first, rather than acting *in addition* to it.

`-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);` should return the element to its original (pre-translation) position. See:

- http://jsfiddle.net/pRdTE/

Comment: Exactly, you wouldn't expect a rule `font-size: 12px;` and then another rule of `font-size: 16px;` to result in 28 pixel high letters.

Comment: -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); did the trick, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Before applying transform you could save the current value of `-webkit-transform`. When undoing just restore the saved value.

Comment: Good idea — if you wanted to apply multiple undoable transforms to an element, you’d need to do this.